# Kafka Streams Fault Tolerance with Offset Management in Parellel

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

**Description** :

I have one Kafka Stream application which is consuming from a topic.
The events are coming at high volumes.

KafkaStream will consume the events as a terminal operation and club the events in a bunch say 1000 events and writes it to AWS S3.

I have threads that are writing to s3 in parallel after consuming events from Kafka topic.

Not using kafka-connector-s3 due to some business application logics and processings.

**Problem** ::

I want the application to be fault-tolerant don't want to loose messages.

--> CRASH SCENARIO

Suppose the application has 10 threads all are running and trying to put the events in S3, and a crash happens, in that case, since the KafkaStream has ( enable.auto.commit = false )and we cannot commit the offset manually and all the threads have consumed messages from Kafka topic.
In this case, KafkaStreams has already committed the offset after reading but it could not have processed the events to S3.

I need a mechanism so that I can be sure of that what was the last offset till the events get written to the S3 file successfully.
And In crash scenarios, how should I deal with this and how to manage the Kafka offsets in Kafka Streams as I am using say 10 threads. What if some failed to write to s3 and some are passed. How do I ensure the ordering of offset getting successfully processed to s3 or not?

Let me know if I am not clear to describe my problem statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can assure you that `enable.auto.commit` is set to `false` in Kafka Streams. The Javadocs at https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.html state

> "enable.auto.commit" (false) - Streams client will always disable/turn off auto committing

You are right that Kafka Streams will automatically commit in more or less regular intervals. However, Kafka Streams waits until records are processed before committing the corresponding offsets. That means you would at least get at-least-once guarantees and not lose messages.

As far as I understand your application, your terminal processor does not block until the records are sent to S3. That means, Kafka Streams cannot know when the sending is completed. Kafka Streams just sees that the terminal processor completed its processing and then -- if the commit interval elapsed -- it commits the offsets.

You say

> Not using kafka-connector-s3 due to some business application logics and processings.

Could you put the business application logic in the Kafka Streams application, write the results to a Kafka topic with operator `to()`, and then use the kafka-connector-s3 to send the messages in that topic to S3?
I am not a connect expert, but I guess that would make sure that messages are not lost and would make your implementation simpler.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks .  In my use case I actually wanted to consume messages from kafka and make a bunch of it say 5000 messages and writes it to s3,since writing to s3 is a time-consuming operation. Now if I start consuming from streams till 5000 messages and then do a S3 write, the offset will get committed till 5000 messages and if s3 writes fails . I am thinking of using Kafka Consumer as it gives the support of manually committing the offset. I belive kafka streams is best suited when you want to read and write to kafka topic, but here I am just reading and doing the terminal operation.

Comment: what is your say on this regarding kafka streams vs kafka consumers.??

Comment: If you want to have the most control about offset commits, you should use Kafka consumers. Note that in Kafka Streams you can also request a commit if you use an operation that has access to the `ProcessorContext`, e.g., `process()` or `transform()`. With `commit.interval.ms` you can control the interval of the commit that is automatically done by Kafka Streams.

Comment: Regarding, writing to S3 with multiple threads, I would consider scaling with the  number of partitions of your input topic by using more stream threads and/or run more Kafka Streams client in parallel (or more Kafka consumers). If your input partition has few partitions you can first write the messages of your input topic to a topic with more partitions and then read from that topic and scale by partition number.

Comment: You haven't answered my question about whether it would be an option to first use Kafka Streams to apply your business logic, write the messages to a topics and then use the S3 connector. If it is not an option, I would be interested why it is not an option? Using Kafka Streams and Connect unburdens you from implementing low level functionality like offset management in case of failures.

Comment: I am not using stream and connect combination. because as told I need to write chunk(5000) of messages in s3 file and also I need to generate a corresponding manifest file(this have path of original file) from the original file generated which has one-one mapping. Thats, why I am avoiding, connect. Also I highly want to control the offset for failure scenarios and will only commit the offset when both the message chunk file and its corresponding manifest file will successfully written to s3. That is why I am not using it.

Comment: Yes I can parellalize by having enough partitions and enough consumers in one consumer group. Does it sound okay or you can suggest anything better.

Comment: I do not have more suggestions. I think you know your project best.

Answer (score 0):

Using kafka-stream ,you could aggragate 5000 messages from source topic to one big message and send the big one to another topic like middle_topic. You need another proceccor source from the middle_topic and sink to s3 using s3-connector.